# Call lifecycle methods on container component created with connect()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I would like to call `componentDidMount()` on the container component that is created by this `connect()`ed component:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { formStyles } from '../../style'
import { DimenInput } from '../dimenInput/DimenInput'
import { updateDimension } from '../../actions/updateDimension.action'
import React from 'react'
import { updateVolume } from '../../actions/updateDimension.action'
import calcVol from '../../calcVol'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  height1: state.get('height').get('height1').toString(),
  height2: state.get('height').get('height2').toString()
})

const updateHeight = (text, number) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(updateDimension('height', text, number))
  let litres = calcVol(getState())
  dispatch(updateVolume(litres))
}

let Height = (props) => (
  <View style={formStyles.container}>
    <DimenInput
      value={props.height1}
      onChangeText={text => props.updateHeight(text, 1)}
    />
    <Text style={formStyles.text}>{'FT'}</Text>
    <DimenInput
      value={props.height2}
      onChangeText={text => props.updateHeight(text, 2)}
    />
    <Text style={formStyles.text}>{'IN'}</Text>
  </View>
)
Height.propTypes = {
  height1: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  height2: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  updateHeight: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

Height = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { updateHeight }
)(Height)

export default Height
```

Is it possible? I try to use connect() because it does some performance optimisations. Or do I just need to create the container component manually to add lifecycle methods?

The main aim of this is that I need to call a method on app startup. Not on component startup. So if there is another way to do that then I'm interested to know about it. [There is a good way to do it with react router `onEnter()`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JicUNpwLzLY) however I do not have a react router as it is a single page app so no routes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to lifecycle methods of a React Component, you'll need to use an object extended from `React.Component`. You can achieve this by creating your component using `React.createClass` or ES6 class notation instead of using a functional component like you are dong now with your arrow function.

[React top level API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html)

```
var Height = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function(){
    //...
  }
});
```

ES6 approach:

```
class Height extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    //...
  }
  componentDidMount(){
     //...
  }
}
```